# Why do I have to do a setenforce 0 to cluster tomcat on Scientific Linux using mod_proxy

Tags: tomcat, http, mod-proxy, selinux

Why do I have to do a setenforce 0 to cluster tomcat on Scientific Linux using mod_proxy

I am using Scientific Linux release 6.2 and trying to get mod_proxy working with httpd and tomcat.

I want to have two tomcat nodes running on the box and so I need to change the 2nd tomcat node ajp port to something diff then 8009 like 8109, But once I change the port on Scientific Linux it stops working but I have found if I do a

**setenforce 0**

it works then.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing and if anyone knows a better what to get tomcat nodes working on  Scientific Linux without doing a setenforce 0

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SELinux profile is blocking connections to non-standard ports. You'll need to change the ruleset to allow tomcat on the new port if you wish to continue running in enforcing mode.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Step one, learn SElinux. Step two, learn how to write SELinux policies (aka rulesets). I'm in the middle of step one.